# MySQL - difference between CET and CEST

Tags: mysql, time, timezone

I need to move some tables from MySQL database to PostgreSQL.
So i've checked, which time zone is MySQL server using by checking system variable:

```
system time zone    CET
```

`CET` - as far as i know - in contrast of `CEST` - is never more than `UTC+1`.
`CEST` is in summer `UTC+2`. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time

But `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` actually returns `CEST` time (`UTC+2`):

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So i've checked, which time zone is
>   MySQL server using by checking system
>   variable

How did you do this?

Try this query please and tell me the results:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

There can be three types of results.

- SYSTEM

which means, that MySQL uses the timezone settings of your OS

- something like '+01:00' or whatever
  value

which is the difference to the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)

- something like 'Europe/Berlin'

which is basically the same as above, but you have populated your timezone tables in MySQL.

You see, `datetime` values are stored as UTC value internally by MySQL.
So, when you insert '2011-03-30 12:34:56' in your table with the SYSTEM variable set to 'Europe/Berlin' / '+01:00', MySQL calculates the integer representation for '2011-03-30 11:34:56', saves the value in your DB. When you query for your datetime values, MySQL adds that hour again (assuming your timezone settings haven't changed) and presents you the value '2011-03-30 12:34:56'